# 2d pygame scrolling with Sprites and tile based map

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I am currently trying to make a 2d platformer in python with a scrolling camera. Originally I made this game using only rect style objects, but that makes collisions very hard compared to just using sprites.

So now I am rewriting this game using sprites for the enemies and main player, but I cant figure out why the scrolling feature will no longer work. It almost seems as though its a scaling issue but I have no clue.

When I turn scroll off the game works just fine.

Thank you guys, if you see anything that jumps out let me know.
Sorry for kinda messy code I'm still getting used to the whole pygame layout.

```
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init() # initiates pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Platformer')

WINDOW_SIZE = (1200,800)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE,0,32) # initiate the window

display = pygame.Surface((150,100)) # used as the surface for rendering, which is scaled

moving_right = False
moving_left = False
vertical_momentum = 0
air_timer = 0
scroll = [0, 0]
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8, 8))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 100
        self.rect.bottom = 50
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 5
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = y
        self.rect.bottom = x
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -10
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 10
        if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.speedy = -30
        self.rect.x += 0
        self.rect.y += 0
#def load_map(path):
 #   f = open(path + '.txt', 'r')
  #  data = f.read()
   # f.close()
    #data = data.split('\n')
   # game_map = []
   # for row in data:
    #    game_map.append(list(row))
   # return game_map

#ame_map = load_map('data/pictures/map')
game_map = [['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2','2','2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2'],
            ['1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1']]

grass_img = pygame.image.load('data/pictures/Purple_grass.png')
dirt_img = pygame.image.load('data/pictures/purple_tile.png')

player = Player()

def collision_test(rect,tiles):
    hit_list = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
    return hit_list

def move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types = {'top':False,'bottom':False,'right':False,'left':False}
    rect.x += movement[0]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0] > 0:
            rect.right = tile.left
            collision_types['right'] = True
        elif movement[0] < 0:
            rect.left = tile.right
            collision_types['left'] = True
    rect.y += movement[1]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1] > 0:
            rect.bottom = tile.top
            collision_types['bottom'] = True
        elif movement[1] < 0:
            rect.top = tile.bottom
            collision_types['top'] = True
    return rect, collision_types




all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = []
mob1 = Mob(10,10)
mobs.append(mob1)
all_sprites.add(player,mobs)
while True: # game loop
    display.fill((146,244,255)) # clear screen by filling it with blue
    #scroll
    scroll[0] += (player.rect.x - scroll[0] -100 ) / 10
    scroll[1] += (player.rect.y - scroll[1] -52) / 10
    all_sprites.update()

    tile_rects = []
    y = 0
    for layer in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in layer:
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(dirt_img, (x * 8 - int(scroll[0]), y * 8 - int(scroll[1])))
            if tile == '2':
                display.blit(grass_img, (x * 8 - int(scroll[0]), y * 8 - int(scroll[1])))
            if tile != '0':
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * 8, y * 8, 8, 8))
            x += 1
        y += 1

    player_movement = [0,0]
    if moving_right == True:
        player_movement[0] += 1
    if moving_left == True:
        player_movement[0] -= 1
    player_movement[1] += vertical_momentum
    vertical_momentum += 0.3
    if vertical_momentum > 3:
        vertical_momentum = 3

    player.rect,collisions = move(player.rect,player_movement,tile_rects)

    if collisions['bottom'] == True:
        air_timer = 0
        player.jumpCount = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 1


    for mob in mobs:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player,mob):
            #mob.image.fill((255,0,255))
            mobs.pop(mobs.index(mob))
            print("collide")
            all_sprites.remove(mob)

        else:
            mob.image.fill((255,255,0))

    all_sprites.draw(display)


    for event in pygame.event.get(): # event loop
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if air_timer < 6:
                    vertical_momentum = -5
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False
        
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display,WINDOW_SIZE),(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I need the map.txt file to run the game.

Comment: sorry about that, I edited a the post so there is a basic integrated map

Comment: `if tile != '0':` - When you append the tiles, you should adjust the tile rects for the scroll: `tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * 8 - int(scroll[0]), y * 8 - int(scroll[1]), 8, 8))`

Comment: i just tried that out and I get some insane collision bugs, it throws me around the screen and clips through walls.  I'm not sure how the scroll would  affect my collisions but I guess its possible.

Comment: if something doesn't work then use `print()` to see values in variables in different places - and then you can check if they are correct. It is called `print debuging`

Comment: you should calculate `scroll` and add it to all objects when you `blit` then (but not add to they `rect`) - but you add `scroll` only to map and you don't add it to player and enemies. You should create method `draw(screen, scroll)` in every sprite and use it instead of `all_sprites.draw(display)` - ie. `for item in all_sprites: item.draw(display, scroll)`

Answer (score 2):

First: you should calculate `scroll` after all moves and collisions.

Second: you have to substract `scroll` from all objects - even player and mobs

```
for item in all_sprites:
    display.blit(item.image, (item.rect.x - scroll[0], item.rect.y - scroll[1]))
```

---

Minimal working code.

You `scroll` works but it is not smooth so I prefere simpler version

```
scroll[0] = int(player.rect.centerx - 75) # surface_width//2
scroll[1] = int(player.rect.centery - 50) # surface_height//2
```

Both are in code but in comments

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# --- constants ---

WINDOW_SIZE = (1200, 800)

# --- classes ---

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8, 8))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 100
        self.rect.bottom = 50
        
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 5
        
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = y
        self.rect.bottom = x
        
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -10
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 10
        if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.speedy = -30
        self.rect.x += 0
        self.rect.y += 0

# --- functions ---

#def load_map(path):
 #   f = open(path + '.txt', 'r')
  #  data = f.read()
   # f.close()
    #data = data.split('\n')
   # game_map = []
   # for row in data:
    #    game_map.append(list(row))
   # return game_map

def collision_test(rect,tiles):
    hit_list = []

    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
            
    return hit_list

def move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types = {'top':False,'bottom':False,'right':False,'left':False}
    
    rect.x += movement[0]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0] > 0:
            rect.right = tile.left
            collision_types['right'] = True
        elif movement[0] < 0:
            rect.left = tile.right
            collision_types['left'] = True
            
    rect.y += movement[1]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1] > 0:
            rect.bottom = tile.top
            collision_types['bottom'] = True
        elif movement[1] < 0:
            rect.top = tile.bottom
            collision_types['top'] = True
            
    return rect, collision_types

# --- main ---

# you could put in class Map
#ame_map = load_map('data/pictures/map')
game_map = [['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2','2','2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2'],
            ['1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1']]


# - init -

pygame.init() 

pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Platformer')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE,0,32) # initiate the window

display = pygame.Surface((150,100)) # used as the surface for rendering, which is scaled

moving_right = False   # you could put in class Player
moving_left = False    # you could put in class Player
vertical_momentum = 0  # you could put in class Player
air_timer = 0          # you could put in class Player
scroll = [0, 0]        # you could put in class Player

#grass_img = pygame.image.load('data/pictures/Purple_grass.png')
#dirt_img = pygame.image.load('data/pictures/purple_tile.png')

grass_img = pygame.surface.Surface((8,8))  # you could put in class Map
grass_img.fill((0, 255, 0))                # you could put in class Map
                    
dirt_img = pygame.surface.Surface((8,8))  # you could put in class Map
dirt_img.fill((255, 64, 64))              # you could put in class Map

player = Player()
mobs = [Mob(10, 10)]

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player,mobs)

# - you can get it once - # you could put in class Map

tile_rects = []
for y, layer in enumerate(game_map):
    for x, tile in enumerate(layer):
        if tile != '0':
            tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * 8, y * 8, 8, 8))

# - loop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - all updates -
    
    all_sprites.update()

    player_movement = [0,0]
    if moving_right == True:
        player_movement[0] += 1
    if moving_left == True:
        player_movement[0] -= 1
    player_movement[1] += vertical_momentum
    vertical_momentum += 0.3
    if vertical_momentum > 3:
        vertical_momentum = 3

    player.rect,collisions = move(player.rect,player_movement,tile_rects)

    if collisions['bottom'] == True:
        air_timer = 0
        player.jumpCount = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 1

    for mob in mobs:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player,mob):
            #mob.image.fill((255,0,255))
            mobs.pop(mobs.index(mob))
            print("collide")
            all_sprites.remove(mob)

        else:
            mob.image.fill((255,255,0))

    # - all draws -
    
    # scroll calculate after all moves 
    scroll[0] = int(player.rect.centerx - 75) # surface_width//2
    scroll[1] = int(player.rect.centery - 50) # surface_height//2

    #scroll[0] += (player.rect.x - scroll[0] -100 ) / 10
    #scroll[1] += (player.rect.y - scroll[1] -52) / 10
    
    display.fill((146,244,255)) # clear screen by filling it with blue

    for y, layer in enumerate(game_map):
        for x, tile in enumerate(layer):
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(dirt_img, (x * 8 - scroll[0], y * 8 - scroll[1]))
            if tile == '2':
                display.blit(grass_img, (x * 8 - scroll[0], y * 8 - scroll[1]))

    for item in all_sprites:
        display.blit(item.image, (item.rect.x - scroll[0], item.rect.y - scroll[1]))
    #all_sprites.draw(display)

    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, WINDOW_SIZE), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

    # - all events -
    
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # event loop
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if air_timer < 6:
                    vertical_momentum = -5
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with more classes and other changes (ie. [pygame.math.Vector2()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html))

```
# PE8: all imports at the beginning
import pygame, sys
#from pygame.locals import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- constants ---

WINDOW_SIZE = (1200, 800)

# --- classes --- # PEP8: all classes before main part

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                        # PEP8: empty line before method
    def __init__(self):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  # Python 2 & 3
        super().__init__() # only Python 3
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8, 8))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 255))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 100
        self.rect.bottom = 50
        
        self.is_jump = False   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        self.jump_count = 5    # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        
        self.movement = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.vertical_momentum = 0
        self.air_timer = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speed.x = 0
        #self.rect.x += self.speed.x

    def draw(self, screen, offset):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.move(-offset))
        
class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  # Python 2 & 3
        super().__init__() # only Python 3

        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = y
        self.rect.bottom = x
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -10
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 10
        if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.speedy = -30
        self.rect.x += 0
        self.rect.y += 0
        
    def draw(self, screen, offset):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.move(-offset))
        
#def load_map(path):
 #   f = open(path + '.txt', 'r')
  #  data = f.read()
   # f.close()
    #data = data.split('\n')
   # game_map = []
   # for row in data:
    #    game_map.append(list(row))
   # return game_map

class Map():
    
    def __init__(self, game_map):
        self.game_map = game_map
        
        #self.grass_img = pygame.image.load('data/pictures/Purple_grass.png')
        #self.dirt_img = pygame.image.load('data/pictures/purple_tile.png')

        self.grass_img = pygame.surface.Surface((8,8))
        self.grass_img.fill((0, 255, 0))
                            
        self.dirt_img = pygame.surface.Surface((8,8))
        self.dirt_img.fill((255, 64, 64))

        # - you can calculate it only once -

        self.tile_rects = []

        for y, layer in enumerate(self.game_map):
            for x, tile in enumerate(layer):
                if tile != '0':
                    self.tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x*8, y*8, 8, 8))

    def draw(self, screen, offset):
        
        for y, layer in enumerate(self.game_map):
            for x, tile in enumerate(layer):
                if tile == '1':
                    display.blit(self.dirt_img, (x*8 - offset.x, y*8 - offset.y))
                elif tile == '2':
                    display.blit(self.grass_img, (x*8 - offset.x, y*8 - offset.y))
        
# --- functions --- # PEP8: all functions before main part

def collision_test(rect, tiles):
    hit_list = []
    
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
            
    return hit_list

def move(player, map_game):
    
    collision_types = {'top': False, 'bottom': False, 'right': False, 'left': False} # PEP8: spaces
    
    player.rect.x += player.movement.x
    
    hit_list = collision_test(player.rect, map_game.tile_rects)
    
    for tile in hit_list:
        if player.movement.x > 0:
            player.rect.right = tile.left
            collision_types['right'] = True
            break
        elif player.movement.x < 0:
            player.rect.left = tile.right
            collision_types['left'] = True
            break
            
    player.rect.y += player.movement.y
    
    hit_list = collision_test(player.rect, map_game.tile_rects)
    
    for tile in hit_list:
        if player.movement.y > 0:
            player.rect.bottom = tile.top
            collision_types['bottom'] = True
            break
        elif player.movement.y < 0:
            player.rect.top = tile.bottom
            collision_types['top'] = True
            break
            
    return collision_types

# --- main ---

#ame_map = load_map('data/pictures/map')
game_map = [['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2','2','2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
            ['2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2'],
            ['1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
            ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1']]


# - init -

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Platformer')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32) # initiate the window

display = pygame.Surface((150, 100)) # used as the surface for rendering, which is scaled

scroll = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

map_data = Map(game_map)
player = Player()
mobs = [Mob(10, 10), Mob(50, 50)]

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player, mobs)

# - main loop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - all updates -
    #all_sprites.update()

    player.movement.update(0, 0)
    
    if player.moving_right == True:
        player.movement.x += 1
            
    if player.moving_left == True:
        player.movement.x -= 1
        
    player.movement.y += player.vertical_momentum
    
    player.vertical_momentum += 0.3
    if player.vertical_momentum > 3:
        player.vertical_momentum = 3

    collisions = move(player, map_data)

    if collisions['bottom'] == True:
        player.air_timer = 0
        player.jump_count = 0
        player.vertical_momentum = 0
    else:
        player.air_timer += 1

        
    for mob in mobs:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, mob):
            #mob.image.fill((255,0,255))
            mobs.pop(mobs.index(mob))
            print("collide")
            all_sprites.remove(mob)
        else:
            mob.image.fill((255,255,0))

    # - all draws -

    # scroll
    scroll.update(player.rect.centerx - 75, player.rect.centery - 50)

    offset = pygame.math.Vector2(int(scroll.x), int(scroll.y))

    display.fill((146, 244, 255))  # PEP8: spaces after `,`

    map_data.draw(display, offset)
    
    for item in all_sprites:
        item.draw(display, offset)

    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, WINDOW_SIZE), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
    
    # - all events -

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # event loop
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.moving_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.moving_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if player.air_timer < 6:
                    player.vertical_momentum = -5
                    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.moving_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.moving_left = False
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was extremely helpful, I was stuck on that for so long. Thank you again!!!